# Playlist limited to random subset never changes

Tags: music.app, playlist

We have thousands of songs in a particular genre on a MacBook Pro (which still has 80% free space).  One of our iPads has room for those but the other does not.  So we created a Smart playlist to randomly include twelve hours.  When that syncs to the iPad, it always contains the **same** songs in the **same** order.  There is a [way to change the selection](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/124088/how-to-regenerate-random-smart-playlist-in-itunes-11), but it’s a bit messy.  **How can we make it update the selection on every sync, or on a schedule?**